# Migrating data from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have to migrate existing data which is in `SQL Server 2000` to `SQL Server 2005`. The schema of two databases is different. For Example `Locations` table in SS2000 is split into two tables and has different columns. **This is one time activity. After successful migration I don't need old db anymore.**

- What is the best way to transfer data from one SQL Server to another having different schemas?

I can write stored procedures to fetch data from `SQL Server 2000` and `insert/update` tables in `SQL Server 2005`.

- What about `SSIS`? I don't have any experience with this and is this better to create package of `SSIS` because I don't need this again and need to learn it first.

**EDIT:This edit is after answer from @AgentDBA:**

One example of data in Old db and how I need this in new db is:

`Customers` table in Old DB has column `FullName` like **'James White'** but in new db there are two columns `FirstName` and `LastName` so data in this should be **'James'** in `FirstName` and **'White'** in `LastName`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't move to SQL 2008?  If you are going to go through the work to convert might as well get to the latest.

Comment: @Matt: the latest being SQL Server 2008 **R2**, to be exact...

Comment: Cleansing name data is a minefield. Ive done it in the past and it wasnt unusual to see titles creep into the Full Name eg "Mr A Jones" or have surname then first name "Jones A" or any other kind of non standard formating. The only way to really do this is to keep iterating through a process where the name data gets better and better with each pass. Once it is clean then transfer to the new database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be an excellent exercise to use this as an opportunity to learn SSIS, I imagine real world deadline pressures will dictate that you're better off sticking with the tools you know (T-SQL, stored procs) rather than trying to learn something brand new, especially for a single use transformation like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Data Import Wizard from SQL 2005 to import the data for you.

Right click on the database choose **Tasks**, **Import Data** this will lead you through a nice wizard that will ask where you are getting the data from and where the data will end up.

Admitedly you would need to do this for each table you are importing the data to in the new SQL2005 database so it can be long winded. However if you save the package (which it should ask you near the end of the wizard) to the desktop then it will save as an SSIS package which is a good way to start to learn SSIS.

Plus as the package is saved you can run it again should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If the two databases are on different servers, SSIS will handle the cross server movement easily while in T-SQL you will have to have linked servers set up. That isn't a big deal as long as you are aware that you need to do it, but some dbas don't allow them on their systems, so if you can't set up a linked server for political reasons, SSIS is the better choice. Otherwise, I'd go with what you know since it is a one-time only thing unless you will be doing lots of other data imports as well in the future (do you currently have lots of DTS packages?). In this case, might as well get started learning SSIS now as it isn't so very simple to learn and there is typically more time to learn before the new db goes live thatn after when the clients are cranky becasue their data isn't in and they sent you the file a week ago.

Comment: Thanks, 1) No DTS Packages. 2) I do know about Linked server but I think there is not need of linked server. I can create a new db in SQL Server 2005 and restore the backup of SQL Server 2000 db on this new DB in SS2K5 and use this to migrate data. This way both DBs would be on same server and easy to fetch data from old db and insert in new one.

Comment: Then I would use t-SQl to do this one time task. Although save the scripts, as you may need to run several times if the data is changeing while you are devloping.